# svg transform parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to get the original transform (40) minus X and then set g to the new tranform value.(40-x,20). What is the better way then parsing the transform string?

```
<label><input type="checkbox"> Sort values</label> 

<g class="state" transform="translate(40,20)">

d3.select("input").on("change", change);

  function change() {
d3.selectAll(".state").attr("x",50);
    var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll(".state")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { COOL MAGIC});
}
```

Comment: It would be great to explain what you have tried and also provide a valid code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse transform property of svg, there can be two kind of approaches.

**Option A**

//send  Svg Dom element as parameter to this function. It will return X,Y of transform string.

```
function getTransformString(svgElement){
 var transformString=svgElement.getAttribute('transform');
    if(transformString){
        var splitBraces=transformString.split('(');
        splitBraces=splitBraces[1].split(')');
        var splitComma=splitBraces[0].split(',');
        return {
            x:splitComma[0],
            y:splitComma[1]
          }
      }

return null;

}
```

**Option B**
// I will Recommend this approach, because it has minimal Dom manipulation. In this option, keep track of Translate X,Y in local variables.

```
var TransformX=0,TransformY=0;

function setSvgTransform(x,y,svgElement){
TransformX=x;
TransformY=y;
var translateString='translate('+x+','+y+')';
svgElement.setAttribute('transform',translateString);
}

function changeSvgTrasform(svgElement){
// now here we do not need to parse transform string to get current value of transform.

var Current_TX=TransformX;
var Current_TY=TransformY;

var newTX=Current_TX-40;

setSvgTransform(newTX,Current_TY,svgElement);

}
```